# Do subqueries ignore an outer WHERE condition if it has it's own WHERE condition?

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

I want a SQL query to follow the conditions of a WHERE statement, except those that are subqueries. In the example below, I'd like to get all entries from the past week, but I want the subqueries to ignore that outer WHERE clause, but I'm not sure of how it will behave.

For example:

```
SELECT
ProductID,
SUM(CASE WHEN from_source = 'button' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 'Used Button',
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tracking WHERE from_source = 'button') 'Used Button to date'
FROM tracking
WHERE date_entered > (GETDATE() - 7)
GROUP BY ProductID
```

Expected output, where the second column is calculating based on outer WHERE, and subquery is not looking at the outer WHERE:

ProductID | Used Button | Used Button to date

123 | 5 | 102

456 | 8 | 175

Comment: Yes, your `Used Button to date` column will return all data, not just that with a `date_entered` less than seven days old.

Comment: Show your expected output

Comment: It will behave exactly the way it behaved when you tested it before you posted on SO.   You did test it before you posted on SO, didn't you?

Comment: If you want a result line per productid, you must *group by* productid. Add this to Gordon's answer and you're there.

Answer (score 1):

You could write the query just using conditional aggregation:

```
select sum(case when date_entered > (GETDATE() - 7) then 1 else 0
           end) as UsedButton,
       count(*) as UsedButtonToDate
from tracking
where from_source = 'button';
```

This seems like a simpler approach.

By the way, you shouldn't use single quotes for column aliases.  Either name the columns with something that doesn't have to be escaped (as above) or use square braces.